# How to dynamically change the CSS properties of a Leaflet Map Marker's PopUp based on the active basemap tile layer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, folium

**NOTE:** I use **Folium in Python** to produce a map as an **HTML output file**, the map uses **Leaflet**. This question regards the HTML output file so it's about **HTML CSS JavaScript**.
I'm still noob when it comes to JavaScript so I'd appreciate a detailed explanation if you post about JS, Thanks.

---

I need to alter the **CSS properties** of the **PopUp window of the Marker** on the map based on the active basemap tile layer;

- I have two basemaps;

  - **OpenStreetMap** with white tiles.
  - **CartoDBDark_Matter** with black tiles.
- I have a layer of Markers: The marker has a PopUp that appears on-click: **Marker PopUp:**

  - It has a transparent blurry background to not obstruct the view when open.
  - Black color Font

By default, the font color is set to "#333" with an opaque white background, which works fine no matter the active basemap but I changed it background to blurry transparent for my needs which cause this issue I'm facing.
The map generates its own CSS and JS (and lots of other HTML), I just override the style with my own CSS.

Right now, the font color is set to "#333", which works fine with the white/light basemap (OpenStreetMap), but becomes difficult to read the text with the black/dark basemap (CartoDBDark_Matter).

The basemap layers are stored in the HTML code as `L.tileLayer` objects, and are added to a layer control. How can I use JavaScript (or something else) to check which basemap layer is currently active, and dynamically change the font color of the marker popup to **#fff** or **#333** accordingly?

### Preview:

**This is what's going on:**
How PopUp font looks on Dark/Light Theme Map (preview):
[image]

**What I want to achieve:**
How font should work on Dark/Light Theme Map (preview)
[image]

For now I keep working on it so things (layer names) may change, I used `color: darkslategray;` as a momentary solution but as you can see it's terrible:
color: darkslategray
[image]

##### Links

Link to my project GitHub Page: https://indigowizard.github.io/QuakeEye/map.html
The GH Page is built from the `feature/UI` branch at the moment, so that's where u can get the latest version.

I tried to treat it as a dark mod / light mod situation using JS to alter the CSS but I suck at it so couldn't do anything really.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!